# Quebrar linha ao apertar Enter e Shift + Enter

Tags: javascript, react, input

Tenho um input, e eu preciso de que ele quebre linha ao apertar Enter e Shift + Enter, e somente envie a mensagem ao clicar no botão. Porém ele nao quebra a linha

```
 handleChatInputPress = (e) => {
if ((e.key === "Enter" && e.shiftKey) || e.key === "Enter") {
  return "\n";
} else {
  this.handleSendButtonClick();
}


 return (
  <div className="chat-input-container d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <Input
      className="form-control flex-grow-1"
      type="text"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      value={messageInput}
      onKeyPress={(e) => {
        if (enableSendMessage) {
          handleChatInputPress(e);
        }
      }}
      onChange={(e) => handleChatInputChange(e)}
    />
    <div>
```

Comment: Inputs não suportam quebras de linha mesmo, será que o que você procura não é um `textarea`?